# Why does EmberJS throws out an error when I use {{#link-to 'index'}}?

Tags: ember.js

When I have a link in my template to `index` using the `link-to` helper, like so: `{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}`, exactly as it's demonstrated on the documentation page [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/), I get the following error in the console and the application will not render:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null
```

Comment: Can you reproduce a jsbin with this error? You can use http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ to get all the dependencies

Comment: Here's is a JSbin with the example from the site copied in. It works without error. We'd really need a JSBin of what you've coded to help debug what you're seeing.